# WebView doesn't load in tableViewCell

Tags: swift, uiwebview, tableview

I am trying to load a youtube video in a tableViewCell but it will not load, the URL gets passed fine but for some reason won't load. Am I going wrong somewhere in the code?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mediaCell") as? MediaCell else {return UITableViewCell()}


        let media = mediaArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(url: media)
        return cell
    }

class MediaCell: UITableViewCell, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.webView?.delegate = self

    }

    func configureCell(url: String){

        if let url = URL(string: url){

            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webView?.loadRequest(request)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just built a new project from scratch and it worked fine with your code, are you sure your URLs are valid? Also are they http or https? If http, are you allowing arbitrary loads in `App Transport Security Settings` in `Info.plist`? Just put a break point in configureCell method right before loading request as `print(url)`to see if your URLs are actually correct.

Comment: URL is valid, it was working fine when It was just a single webView not in a tableView, I think it has something to do with setting the delegates but I could be wrong

Comment: It was working in a tableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the webView outlet was connected to the content view instead of the cell

Answer (score 0):

You try to check withIdentifier: "mediaCell" the same storyboard

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mediaCell", for: indexPath) as? MediaCell {
        let media = mediaArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(url: media)
        return cell
    }
    //print("some error")
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: The identifiers are the same